# Ribbon giving 404 response on WebLogic 12c

Tags: microservices, jhipster, netflix-zuul, netflix-ribbon

I have the following spring boot applications structure:

- gateway application as zuul proxy.
- backend application as microservice.

When I hit a rest service in backend through zuul routing using ribbon load balancer, give me 404 response. But when I remove the ribbon load balancing, It works fine.

This happens just when I deploy on web logic. It is working fine on tomcat.

Why is this happening? Is there any solution for this?

Below my code before and after.

***Before change (not working on weblogic):***

```
zuul:
    routes:
        serviceName:
            path: /serviceName/**
            serviceId: serviceName

serviceName:
    ribbon:
        listOfServers: localhost:8081
```

***After change (ribbon section removed / working on weblogic):***

```
zuul:
    routes:
        serviceName:
            path: /serviceName/**
            url: http://localhost:8081
```